# How to add +x just for user with chmod?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, chmod

`chmod +x file` changes a file from rw-r--r-- to rwxr-x-r-x but really I only wanted rwx-r--r-- is this possible?

Comment: You'd be much more likely to get a good answer on [Unix/Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: `chmod u+x file`. u=user, g=group, o=others.

Comment: @jweyrich put that as an answer -- that's more elegant and better than my way...

Comment: The question probably has dozens of duplicates, but I posted it as an answer anyway. Glad it helped.

Comment: @evamvid this question is perfectly on topic here, no reason to suggest the OP take it to [unix.se]. And I say that as a regular of both sites.

Comment: nicely put @terdon :)

Comment: @terdon also speaking as a regular of both sites, I didn't mean that this question was off-topic on this site; I was just trying to point out that, in general, Linux-specific questions will get better and/or more complete answers on [U+L SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @evamvid not true, U&L is great for the more obscure, in-depth answers, this is an elementary question about the basic options of a standard command. U&L would not find it very interesting and would likely ignore it. This is a better home for this type of question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To change only the permission for the current user, you can use:

```
chmod u+x <file>
```

Where u=user, g=group, o=others.

If you want to enforce the permissions you mentioned, this would be the ideal:

```
chmod u=rwx,go=r file
```

Optionally, you can do the same using the [octal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Numeric_notation), as follows:

```
chmod 744 <file>
```

This will set `rwx` (the 7) for user, and `r` (the 4's) for group and others.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `chmod u=rwx,go=r file`.

In my case, that gives the permissions as `rwx-r--r--`, which I think is what you meant.